# I am getting this error: ERROR running force:source:deploy: The Flow named ListingID_Update was not found in the workspace

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, package.xml

I am receiving this error while trying to deploy to a sandbox using sfdx source deploy commands.

This the error:

> ERROR running force:source:deploy:  The Flow named ListingID_Update
>   was not found in the workspace.

This is the command that I am using:

> sfdx force:source:deploy -u $SF_USERNAME_CFIT -c -w 600 -x manifest/Incrementalpackage.xml -l NoTestRun

This is the Incrementalpackage.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
    <members>OrderItemHandler</members>
  </types>
  <types>
    <name>Flow</name>
    <members>ListingID_Update.flow-meta.xml</members>
  </types>
  <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

And the Flow mentioned in the Incrementalpackage.xml is also in the VS Code workspace as shown below.

[image]

The Incrementalpackage.xml works if we are deploying from another branch but doesnt work if we deploy from this current branch. Same file and same Incrementalpackage.xml.

Tried everything to resolve this can't seem to figure it out maybe someone else might know how to resolve.

Also, VS Code is giving me an error on this file even though the file doesn't have errors.

[image]

In the problems tab in VS CODE for that file it shows this message:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could you expand what do you mean by this branch ? You mean git branch ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yes Git branch. So, both branches include the same code base. But it's deploying from one branch and not the other branch. We have deployed flows before and never had issues until now. But we have seen this error come up numerous times for other metadata types as well.

Comment: Which operating system are you on ?

Answer (score 4):

We found the issue. Someone had added the flows folder to the forceignore file in VS CODE thats why we were not able to deploy to any of our sandboxes.

This problem is now resolved.